# Python 3.8.6 says I have a newer version of Python installed, but I don't

Tags: python, windows

I just installed Python 3.9.0 and I found out Pygame hasn't been fully released yet in this Python version. I then tried to uninstall Python and it said it uninstalled with no errors. Then, I tried to reinstall Python 3.8.6, and I got the following error message.

```
A newer version of Python has already been installed on this device.
```

I checked the control panel to see if Python 3.9.0 was still on my computer, and it wasn't. The only Python app was the Python launcher, and I got an error message when I tried to uninstall it. If I type py in the start menu a Python command prompt appears, but I can't open it. Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: This is going to sound trite, but did you reboot between uninstalling 3.9.0 and installing 3.8.6? Some uninstall operations can be deferred until reboot, and it might help to reboot first.

Comment: Pygame for Python 3.9 has been available [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) since May.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm going to reboot now.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Rebooting didn't work.

Comment: @YeetYeet: Sorry, worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the version of Python by entering to the console using the command "python" in Command Prompt or Terminal to see if Python still shows the 3.9.0 version, if it does go to Control Panel and uninstall it from there, then try restarting the PC as the comment refers. If running the command throws you to the Windows Store try "python3".
If that doesn't work then uninstall Python completely and delete it's folder from the PC, restart and install again. I highly recommend Python installer from their website. To me the store edition gave problems with modules.
If the installer from the website does not work, then try version from the Windows Store, this version will give from the installer even CMD access.

Comment: I just typed it in the command prompt and I didn't get an output.
I typed:
```python -v```
Output:

Comment: Just type python and it should enter the console if it's available. If does not try installing the desired version.

Comment: It just takes me to the microsoft store, so I'm guessing it isn't installed. I will try installing Python again.

Comment: Alright! I recommend the installer from Python instead of the Store version. To my experience, the store version gave me a lot of problems with modules.

Comment: It won't work when I try installing it from python.org, but it is working in the Microsoft Store.

Comment: @xPTM1219 Could you add the steps from the comments into your answer? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way on Windows 11:

First, download the installer of 3.9. Run it, do a repair installation, after that run the installer again, this time choose uninstall.

Next, run the installer of 3.8 to install, installation went successfully.